# AngularJS $timeout loop fires only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following, but what I'm trying to do is have the `$timeout` loop every 10 seconds, but what the below is doing is running the `shuffleArray()` then after 10 seconds it fires it again and that is it. It stops there.

```
    $http.post("/content", {"Data":JSON.stringify($scope.content)}).success(function(data, status, header, config){
        $scope.ourcontent = data;
        shuffleArray($scope.ourcontent);
        $timeout(function() {
            shuffleArray($scope.ourcontent);
        }, 10000);
    });
```

Comment: That's because you're confusing `$timeout` with `$interval`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is $interval, have a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).